# How to add a component to a label?

Tags: java, html, wicket, wicket-1.5

I have the following html:

```
<label wicket:id="drugSearchResult.row.item.label" for="drug_1">[Drug XYZ]  
    <span wicket:id="drugSearchResult.row.item.info">[Information, Price, Other]</span>
</label>
```

But label element are not allowed to add a child component.
Is there any way to achieve this html requirement?

This is the designer's requirement:

> Drug XYZ // **label**
>   Information, Price, Other // **span**

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What is that you want to achive? Put the resulting html that you want to get and what your model objects are.

Comment: I really don't understand why would you do that, why don't you simply do `<label wicket:id="drugSearchResult.row.item.label" for="drug_1">[Drug XYZ]</label><span wicket:id="drugSearchResult.row.item.info">[Information, Price, Other]</span>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure you're using `FormComponentLabel` for the `<label>` element instead of `Label`.

[`Label`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/basic/Label.html)'s purpose is to output text inside the associated element (it can be a `<span>`, `<div>` or almost any other tag).

[`FormComponentLabel`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/FormComponentLabel.html)'s purpose is to model [`<label>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1) tags. They receive the [`FormComponent`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/FormComponent.html) they're related to and automatically output the `for` attribute with the proper value for the dom `id` attribute.

Take a look at the Wicket wiki page on [Form control labels](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Form+control+labels). They're adding components to `FormComponentLabel` there.

If you'd like to avoid using `FormComponentLabel` at all, you shouldn't be giving it a `wicket:id` attribute, and manually set the DOM `id` attribute of the element the `<label>` is going to refer to. Then just use it in the `for` attribute of the `<label>`.

For instance:

**HTML**

```
<input wicket:id="drug">
<label for="drug_1">[Drug XYZ]  
    <span wicket:id="drugSearchResult.row.item.info">[Information, Price, Other]</span>
</label>
```

**Java**

```
TextField drug = new TextField("drug");
drug.setMarkupId("drug_1"); // Make sure this ID is unique in the page!
drug.setOutputMarkupId(true);
add(drug);
Label drugDescription = new Label("drugSearchResult.row.item.label", aModel);
add(drugDescription);
```

Comment: Thanks, never known about the FormComponentLabel. But it does get rather verbatim.

Comment: @bert it might be, but is also quite useful. You can even output required field symbols (i.e. `*`) in the label automatically based on `isRequired()`, and use the component's `get/setLabel()` for the text :)

Comment: I have a usecase for this right now, so its good I stumble over this. Does the label text is i18n (i.e. loads from reasource files)?

Comment: yeah, indeed! [`setLabel`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/FormComponent.html#setLabel(org.apache.wicket.model.IModel)) receives a `Model`, so `StringResourceModel` would be fine here. This way you can always match the field name validators output in their errors with the text inside the `<label>` :)

Comment: we use wicket:message right now, but have the requirement to include error markup. so this comes handy ;)

Answer (score 1):

#### Using properties and `<wicket:message>`

For me, the approach below is useful.
In my project, I have only one location per page where the text for the `<label>`s and validation messages is defined. It's the properties file of the web page.

The additional `<div>`s and their class attributes are from Bootstrap.

```html
<div class="form-group required">
    <label wicket:for="customer.name1">
        <wicket:message key="customer.name1"/>
    </label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" wicket:id="customer.name1" required class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>
```

Java

```java
add(new RequiredTextField<String>("customer.name1")
         .setLabel(new StringResourceModel("customer.name1")));
```

customerPage.properties

```
# siehe wicket-core-7.9.0-sources.jar!/org/apache/wicket/Application_de.properties
Required='${label}' ist erforderlich
customer.name1=Name 1
customer.name2=Name 2
customer.department=Abteilung
customer.phone=Telefon
customer.active=aktiv
```